# Are left-handed people better at mathematics?

Tags: physiology, mathematics

During a math exam, I was told: "You are left-handed, you should become a mathematician."

I searched online and, sure enough, there are some web-sites claiming that left-handed people tend to be better at mathematics.

For example, [Fact Retriever](http://www.factretriever.com/left-handedness-facts) says:

> Studies have suggested that left-handers are more talented in spatial awareness, math, and architecture. Right-handers tend to be more talented verbally.

They cite an entire book as the source.

Is it true?

Comment: Sorry, anecdotal...  I am a mathematician, and have noticed lots of left-handers in that profession.  I was at an academic banquet once, seated next to a psychologist, and asked him about it.  He said, yes: not only mathematics, but all intellectual pursuits...the upper end of the IQ scale has a greater share of left-handers than the general population.  But then he added a caution.  It is also true that the lower end of the IQ scale has a greater share of left-handers than the general population.